# Gitlab runners not activated after installing gitlab-runner in kubernetes cluster - With "New Runner. Has not connected yet" status

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I have set up a Kubernetes cluster and integrated it with my Gitlab repository group. For setting up the CICD feature in my projects I installed GitLab-runner to my Kubernetes cluster.

[Image 1 - Gitlab runner installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ralQg.png)

After installing GitLab-runner into my Kubernetes cluster, I checked the GitLab-managed-apps namespace. pod & deployment are created perfectly.

[Image 2 - output of "Kubectl get all -n gitlab-managed-apps" command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EG5Jr.png)

After these steps, I have checked the runner's tab in my project, noticed one group runner is created.
But it is not in the running state. It shows "New Runner. Has not connected yet".

[Image 3 - Gitlab group runner status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXia7.png)

Due to this, my cicd pipeline failed. Please help me to solve this issue.

Regards,
Gokul

Comment: Have you tried to execute: `gitlab-runner verify`? Also, is there any error message that you see? Any relevant logs that you can share? Also, which version of K8s and runner are you using?

Comment: Thank you for your reply Wytrzymaly. 
I just check the logs of gitlab-runner pod logs, got an error message.

WARNING: Checking for jobs... failed                runner=7NERmo status=couldn't execute POST against https://xxxxxxx.xxxxx.com/api/v4/jobs/request: Post https://xxxxxx.xxxx.com/api/v4/jobs/request: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

How will be adding gitlab certificates to kubernetes cluster? In normal cases we can just add certificate  into a specific path and update the ca-certificate. But in this case how will be managing that.?

Comment: Wytrzymaly, I am using Kubernetes v1.17 with EKS cluster.

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer.
The issue is exactly covered in this thread.

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/24247

Thanks for all
:)

Regards,
Gokul