# gitlab: Runner has never contacted this instance

Tags: gitlab

I added a new virtualbox runner to my gitlab self hosted solution and I'm getting this warning on it:

```
Runner has never contacted this instance
```

and it nevers runs any jobs

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gitlab CI/CD: New runner has not been connected yet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67820925/gitlab-ci-cd-new-runner-has-not-been-connected-yet)

Answer (score 0):

Bouncing the runner will definitely help, else re-register the runner.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Also, you should check the status of the Runner with the below command.

```
gitlab-runner status
```

If you are using the runner in Windows Server, then go to the path where you have stored the `.exe` file and run the below command:

```
.\<.exe> status
```

If the runner is in stopped state, the start the runner by using the same commands but just replace `status` with `start`.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me because I ran registering as a normal user instead of root.

Register the runner again:

1. Go to https://YOUR_INSTANCE.ORG/admin/runners/new and create a new runner
2. Type the returned command **with sudo** in the system on which gitlab-runner sits, like: `sudo gitlab-runner register --url https://YOUR_INSTANCE.ORG --token xabgT5Lto5PLto5Pie`